# Relay timing modification

Tags: relay

I want to increase the armature contact time with pin 87 of any relays when coil is energized.

For instance, if the initial armature contact time is 2 seconds with 87 pin, how to increase the contact timing by 3 or 4 seconds?[image][image]

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide more information about your relay: make, model number, coil voltage, contact configuration, etc. I suggest you read over your question and ask yourself how could anyone provide an answer based on it. What is significant about pin 87?

Comment: yeah, sorry, we have zero idea what you're talking about, since we're not sitting right next to you and hence don't know what you're working with. Everything with at least 87 pins has a pin 87, and as you can imagine, *a lot* of things have at least 87 pins. So, this question is too unclear to be answered :(

Answer (score 1):

Relays in automotive use the 87 designation to indicate the terminal of the Normally Open (NO) contact. DIN 72552 specifies the numbering. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_72552 (which is not entirely consistent with what is actually being used, see first comment below)

[image]

Here is a link to an adjustable timer relay for automotive type relays.

http://hellahd.com/index.php/default/electrics/flasher-and-timer-modules/electrics-category-11/electrics-product-12/

12V, 10A Adjustable Delay Timer Relay (Delay ON or OFF)

https://www.polevolt.co.uk/acatalog/12-volt-Timer-relay.-Configurable-time---delay-on-or-off.-74205.html#SID=78

or

https://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/adjustable-delay-timer-relay-delay-on-or-off-12v-10a.html

or

https://www.amazon.ca/HELLA-152-131-0-900s-Delay-Control/dp/B003C508XO/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?s=automotive&ie=UTF8&qid=1544366749&sr=1-1-fkmr0&keywords=HELLA+delay+time+relay

These are special (expensive).

https://www.arc-components.com/0-742-12-durite-12v-adjustable-programmable-timer-relay.html

https://www.arc-components.com/12v-pre-programmed-delay-off-timer-relays.html

[image]

Comment: According to the referenced DIN document, terminal 87 is supposed to be the common terminal, 87a the normally closed contact, and 87b the normally open contact.

Comment: Yes. It seems that the standard is inconsistent with what the industry had adopted. Either that or the information on the internet is copied wrong and duplicated over and over. I basically go by what the manufactures use for designation. Unless it is inconsistent with what I physically find. In the table on the right it shows 30 for the Common connection rather than 87.